# temporary failure in name resolution - resolve.conf points to 8.8.8.8 but still not working

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I'm connected to the internet, but whenever I ping a website, I just keep getting "Temporary failure in name resolution."

I've already tried the following:

- changing /etc/resolv.conf to include `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4`
- ensuring that there's no symbolic link that's redirecting resolv.conf [as per this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790745/connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet)
- running `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`
- restarting my computer
- deleting the wireless connection and reconnecting

Output of `systemctl status systemd-resolved`:

```
systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-02-13 09:35:20 EST; 19min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 799 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 6677)
     Memory: 8.3M
        CPU: 169ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─799 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Feb 13 09:35:20 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Feb 13 09:35:31 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client set search domain list to: adsroot.itcs.<REDACTED>.edu
Feb 13 09:35:31 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Feb 13 09:35:31 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 10.10.10.10, 10.10.5.5
Feb 13 09:40:14 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client reset search domain list.
Feb 13 09:40:14 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
Feb 13 09:40:14 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Feb 13 09:40:14 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client set search domain list to: adsroot.itcs.<REDACTED>.edu
Feb 13 09:40:14 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Feb 13 09:40:14 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 35.0.0.12, 35.0.0.4`
```

What else can I try?

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: Try setting your `/etc/resolv.conf` file to the non-stub version of it.  I have had great success with this especially with my router giving out DHCP.  `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf` then `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @Terrance Thank you!! That fixed it - I still couldn't connect to the primary network but I was able to limp my way into the guest network and was able to contact my IT department, who gave me a config tool to help me get set up the rest of the way. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Have you edited your network configuration for the wireless *after* adding it to statically set your DNS servers to Google DNS?   Your logs show that DHCP on the wifi network is overriding your DNS settings, hence your problem - `Feb 13 09:40:14 osprey-ThinkPad-T450 systemd-resolved[799]: wlp3s0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 35.0.0.12, 35.0.0.4`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `/etc/resolv.conf` file to the non-stub version of it. I have had great success with this especially with my router giving out DHCP.

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf 

sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Need to reboot?

Comment: @Thirumal You shouldn't have to reboot.  Maybe you need to release and renew the DHCP if this doesn't work.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1024207/231142