# One PC with both wired and wireless interfaces uses only wireless for internet

Tags: networking, internet, interface

I have a Azulle inspire with both wired and wireless interfaces. If I turn off the wireless, I can't connect to the internet but can to other sites on my LAN.  If I turn the wireless back on, everything works fine.  I'm puzzled.  Anyone have any ideas?  I'm running ubuntu 18.04 on the machine in question.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1464895/edit) your question and add more details like the version of Ubuntu you are running?  Also any other info that might help us help you like the output of `ip addr` and `ip route`.  A system can only have one default route that connects to the internet at a time.  Sounds like yours probably isn't flipping a new DHCP route when you turn off your wireless to your Ethernet connection.  You could probably try renewing the IP address for your Ethernet as seen in https://askubuntu.com/a/1024207/231142

Comment: The link worked nicely.  Thanks.  Does this mean I'll have to release/renew manually whenever I change interfaces?

Comment: Only one interface can have the default route to the internet at a time.  It would probably work if you waited on turning off the WiFi before plugging in the Ethernet cable.  Or, you could check your BIOS settings and see if it is one that will turn off the WiFi when an Ethernet connection is connected this way you only have 1 active interface at a time and only 1 route as well.

Comment: The solution given in the link works fine.  So, I need to do this every time I switch interfaces?

Comment: @bobc Unfortunately, yes.  As was stated, only one interface can be the "default route" at a time.  Short of creating multiple configurations in Network Manager that you *manually select* per interface to make this slightly easier (so two wifi entries for the wifi name, one with default route and one without, and two Ethernet interfaces one with default route and one without), you will have to manually modify the connection you're on to define one with the route and one without.  There's no way around that.

Comment: Thank you Thomas.